# What's the difference between {exp:stash:get name="foo"}, {exp:stash:foo} and {stash:foo}?

Tags: stash

Can someone explain to me the difference between `{exp:stash:get name="foo"}`, `{exp:stash:foo}` and `{stash:foo}`?

I'm relatively new to ExpressionEngine, and after discovering Stash, I'm amazed at how powerful of a tool it can be, when used properly.

In reading the documentation and support forums, I've seen reference to all three  tags that, I believe, all serve to retrieve a variable.  However when I try them out, I sometimes find that I get slightly different results when I interchange them.

According to the documentation, `{exp:stash:get name="foo"}`, `{exp:stash:foo}` are the same thing, and I've only seen passing references to the third `{stash:foo}`. Even if they all serve the same purpose, do each have their own particular uses that make them differ from the others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{exp:stash:get name="foo"}` is a module tag. When the template parser encounters it, it calls the `get()` method of the 'stash' module class, which returns the value of `foo`. If `foo` doesn't exist, an empty value is returned, unless the `default=""` parameter has been set.

`{exp:stash:foo}` is a shorter syntax version of the above tag, for convenience.

`{stash:foo}` used on its own (not as a tag pair) is a *placeholder* for a native Stash variable, similar to an ExpressionEngine snippet. When the parser encounters it, it looks up the value of `foo` in a special array that Stash uses to store all variables that have been created previously in the parse order. The value it finds then replaces the placeholder. If it doesn't find a value the placeholder is left in the template.

Which you use depends on parse order. Inside Stash embeds and any blocks of code parsed by Stash, placeholders in the form `{stash:variable}` are parsed *before* ExpressionEngine tags, but *after* snippets. That makes them useful for passing values into tag parameters which are parsed later.

Note that you can also set a ExpressionEngine snippet value by using `type="snippet"`

`{exp:stash:set name="foo" type="snippet"}value{/exp:stash:set}`

This can then be accessed inside EE or Stash embeds and any blocks of code parsed by Stash in the form:

`{foo}`

Answer (score 0):

`{stash:foo}` can be used when using the set pair tag, so for example

```
{exp:stash:set}
    {stash:foo}bar{/stash:foo}
    {stash:bar}foo{/stash:bar}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Would set 2 stash variables, foo and bar respectively. I believe the benefit here is that there's less method calls than the `{exp:stash:set name=""}` alternative (although note this is an assumption).

You can also use `{stash:foo}` when within a setting (whether it's normal or lists) pair tag to 'GET'

```
{exp:stash:set}
    {stash:foo}bar{/stash:foo}
    {stash:bar}foo{/stash:bar}
    {stash:foobar}{stash:foo}{stash:bar}{/stash:foobar}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: Yes, that's in the documentation, but in the GET context, is there a difference?

Comment: What I mean by this is, I believe it's only valid in the SET context and doesn't work in GET.

Comment: Not true. I was having a similar issue to this support question: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/9011#30659 and the answer helped me sort my problems out, which is what prompted me to ask the above question in the first place :)

Comment: Sorry I understand what you mean now. I've updated my answer with my understanding, but I'm not 100% on this one. I'll keep an eye on the thread for any other answers.